# SQLite local db with Firestore using String converter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have `SQLite` database stored locally. I want users to be able to share it and modify it (offcourse users belonging to one group, sort of like note sharing) .

However I don't want o migrate the SQLite database to Firestore because it is very complex and all the joins already built.

So I though about the following:

Everytime a user makes a change to SQLite database, I convert it to string and put it on firestore. This was the string can be loaded on devices and decoded onto SQLite database.

Does this sound like a reasonable solution? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: why for changes not have a update query for your webserver, cause adding other sqlite is so slow

Comment: Not sure I understand what Do u mean by so slow?i dont have webserver as I don't want to deal with its costs plus the storage of user secure data

Comment: Sounds technically feasible to me. Whether this is preferable to convert is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Snake Did you do this thing? What kind of way did you follow?

Comment: I didn't as i thought there was some sort of sql db exporter/importer but there was not. So I had to write a program to select all tables and write it to a file if I wanted to go down that path. I didn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, technically it will work perfectly fine. Is your choice which data type you choose but note that in Cloud Firestore, there are many more. It's true that the String is a common choice because is `UTF-8 encoded` and can hold up to `1 MiB` but there are also other [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) that can help you and which were not present Firebase Realtime database.

These are all data types that are supported in Cloud Firestore:

> - Null values
> - Boolean values
> - Integer and floating-point values, sorted in numerical order
> - Date values
> - Text string values
> - Byte values
> - Cloud Firestore references
> - Geographical point values
> - Array values
> - Map values

Comment: the only reason I thought about using string because I convert the whole database into one string and load it into firestore and then I can get it all back and convert it to SQLite db.